# Storing a DateTime value in web sql

Tags: sqlite, web-sql

I'm confused about the DateTime field type in Web SQL (SQLite?).

Should I store my date/time values as a getTime() in milliseconds, or as a YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:SSS string?

And if storing in milliseconds, what field type should I use?

Comment: select convert(varchar,myDateTime,126) as myDateTime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, I'd use the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format and a `text` column to hold them. SQLite doesn't have any native time types but its native [date and time handling functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) work with ISO 8601 formats:

> All five date and time functions take a time string as an argument. The time string is followed by zero or more modifiers. The strftime() function also takes a format string as its first argument.
>
> The date and time functions use a subset of IS0-8601 date and time formats. The date() function returns the date in this format: YYYY-MM-DD. The time() function returns the time as HH:MM:SS. The datetime() function returns "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS".

So if you're ever going to need to manipulate your timestamps inside the database (and you probably will sooner or later) then you'll want to use `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` strings.

If you won't be manipulating your timestamps inside the database (beyond simple comparisons) then you can probably use a seconds-since-epoch integer without difficulty. Also note that sometimes you can use a seconds-since-epoch value natively:

> The "unixepoch" modifier (11) only works if it immediately follows a timestring in the DDDDDDDDDD format. This modifier causes the DDDDDDDDDD to be interpreted not as a Julian day number as it normally would be, but as Unix Time - the number of seconds since 1970. If the "unixepoch" modifier does not follow a timestring of the form DDDDDDDDDD which expresses the number of seconds since 1970 or if other modifiers separate the "unixepoch" modifier from prior DDDDDDDDDD then the behavior is undefined. Due to precision limitations imposed by the implementations use of 64-bit integers, the "unixepoch" modifier only works for dates between 0000-01-01 00:00:00 and 5352-11-01 10:52:47 (unix times of -62167219200 through 10675199167).

so you can say:

```
SELECT datetime(1092941466, 'unixepoch');
```

and get `'2004-08-19 18:51:06'` back. Specifying the `'unixepoch'` modifier is a bit cumbersome though and causes interesting things to happen when you inevitably forget it:

```
-- 1333482187 is 2012-04-03 19:43:07
sqlite> select strftime('%m', 1333482187, 'unixepoch');
04
sqlite> select strftime('%m', 1333482187);
43
```

As usual, the real answer is *it depends* but ISO 8601 strings are probably your best bet.